# How to use Google offline conversion for Purchase?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a sheet which mentioned all the purchase data of my customers, I want to add all of these in Google Analytics as an e-commerce transaction. So can I send it via API? if yes then how?

I have order_id, source, click_id, campaign, purchase_date, purchase_time, purchase_amt columns in spreadsheet.

Is these data are enough or not for API?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [How to ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can send them with measurement protocol with transaction or purchase: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ti

Measuring Purchases (parameters example)
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#measuring-purchases

However you can't send data for the past, so all transaction will be associated on the day you sent the hit.

Comment: Thanks, I have searched on google for that also, I got this one.https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7014069?hl=en
this way I can upload conversions via Google Sheet. is that correct way?

and one more question. I have mentioned some column names in my question. can you check is it all correct to import in Google Ads or I need another sheet to import?

Comment: That link show you how to import conversions in Google Ads, not in Google Analytics.

Comment: so can you help me to review this column names? is it working well in api of google analytics?

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: Actually my client wants to track offline purchase conversions in Google Analytics, So that's the only purpose.

Comment: You can find the solution to apply in the answer...

Comment: Okay. Thanks Michele Pisani

Comment: You're welcome, since there are no API to do it, that is the only way. I updated my answer where you can find the documentation link with required parameters for purchase.